# Does it make sense to solve Word Count on a Hadoop cluster?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

Many tutorials on Hadoop MapReduce begin with the Word Count example. However, I remember from my distributed computing class (which was before Hadoop's birth) that computing in a distributed fashion results in a speed up only when the subtasks are of coarse granularity, which means that the time of computation exceeds the time of communication. In Word Count, the time complexity (if done with hash tables and assuming a constant limit on the word length) is linear. Hence it seems that paying the cost of transferring the input file to HDFS and of the subsequent Sort & Shuffling phase is not justified. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not clear what you are suggesting the alternative is, but WordCount is like printing Hello World in your favorite language.

It teaches you the basic concepts, it is not intended to be the prime example of how to use MapReduce, or really how to optimize a Hadoop cluster (storing line-delimted text for analysis isn't where Hadoop shines).

Comment: The alternative is sequential. Where does Hadoop shine?

Comment: MapReduce is still sequential... Just in parallel. Processing Splittable / Columnar formats like Parquet and ORC is more performant. Hive and Spark are more commonly used than plain MapReduce in my experience

Comment: Also, the cost to transfering the file to HDFS is a one-time cost. I would not suggest upload a file *only to do word count* on it. For example - https://adamdrake.com/command-line-tools-can-be-235x-faster-than-your-hadoop-cluster.html

Comment: Thank you for the great link. However, on the second thought, note that the original MapReduce paper by Google (page 2) lists Word Count (under the name Count of URL Access Frequency) as one of the "simple examples of **interesting** programs that can be easily expressed as MapReduce computations". According to your reply, Word Count is not interesting.

Comment: It isn't compared to alternatives like K-Means Clustering, Sentiment Analysis or Graph Traversal. Hadoop is over 10 years old. The technology has changed and new "interesting programs" have been made over time. That paper came out in 2004...